T-SQL Update statement with previous row
I have a SQL Server table with these 3 columns
Id, NetWeight, TransactionWeight

I need to update the current row's NetWeight value with the previous row's Netweight + current row's TransactionWeight.
UPDATE Table1
SET NetWeight = TransactionWeight + (previous row NetWeight)

How can I achieve this? I tried with CTE and LAG function, it is updating only first row correctly as the CTE is evaluated only once.
Any help appreciated.

What defines the ordering of your rows? When you say "current row" and "previous row" - what columns defines that order? And please show us the code you tried - the LAG function seems like a very sensible choice - show us that code of yours so we can offer hints how to improve it!

A simple way to solve your task is to join the subquery or CTE within your update command.
So let's create some sample data according to your question:
CREATE TABLE yourtable (Id int, NetWeight int, TransactionWeight int);

INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES
(1,60,50),
(2,40,40),
(3,90,100),
(4,70,60),
(5,80,70),
(6,90,30),
(7,20,80);

Then your idea to use LAG is fine. Following query...
SELECT
  id, NetWeight, TransactionWeight,
  TransactionWeight + COALESCE(LAG(NetWeight) OVER(ORDER BY id),0) AS newWeight
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY id;

...produces the expected result:



id
NetWeight
TransactionWeight
newWeight




1
60
50
50


2
40
40
100


3
90
100
140


4
70
60
150


5
80
70
140


6
90
30
110


7
20
80
170



So we can use this query as subquery or CTE and join it to the table in order to update the rows:
WITH newWeights AS
  (SELECT
    id,
    TransactionWeight + COALESCE(LAG(NetWeight) OVER(ORDER BY id),0) AS newWeight
  FROM yourtable)
UPDATE y
  SET y.NetWeight = nw.newWeight 
FROM 
  yourtable y 
  INNER JOIN newWeights nw
    ON y.id = nw.id;

And now the table looks like this:



Id
NetWeight
TransactionWeight




1
50
50


2
100
40


3
140
100


4
150
60


5
140
70


6
110
30


7
170
80



Just two things left to check, that's up to you:

Do you really find the "previous" or the "next" row using the id column or do you use another column?
What to do if no previous row exists? As you see, I just updated the NetWeight to the TransactionWeight in this case. Change this part if you want something else.

Check these two questions and modify the update command if necessary.
Here the db<>fiddle for this sample data.

UPDATE yourtable
SET NetWeight = subquery.newWeight
FROM (
    SELECT id, TransactionWeight + COALESCE(LAG(NetWeight) OVER(ORDER BY id), 0) AS newWeight
    FROM yourtable
) AS subquery
WHERE yourtable.id = subquery.id;

SELECT * FROM yourtable


Update the previous rows using a subquery to update the records preceding the current ones.
